# Python Fernet TypeError: token must be bytes

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

Here i try to insert new row into a table in a database.

```py
def insert_record():
    values = input('Enter values ').replace(' ', '').split(sep=',')
    values[-1] = f"{f.encrypt(values[-1].encode())}"
    c.execute("INSERT INTO credentials VALUES (?, ?, ?)", values)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I encrypt the last argument `values[-1]` because it will be a password.
when i try to decrypt it

```py
    for item in values:
    print(f.decrypt(item[-1]))
```

i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: token must be bytes
```

I tried so many things and i've been stuck for hours. I can't get rid of the error.

Answer (score 4):

please convert the type from string to byte by adding **b** in the string.
Take a look at the below example:

```
>>> from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
>>> key = Fernet.generate_key()
>>> f = Fernet(key)
>>> token = f.encrypt(b"my deep dark secret")
>>> token
b'...'
>>> f.decrypt(token)
b'my deep dark secret'
```

Comment: i try to encrypt a variable. How to convert the variable value into bytes

Comment: a ="abdsa"
a =bytes(a,'utf-8')