# Python fernet: token must be in bytes

Tags: python, sqlite, encryption, fernet

i would like to add values to the database in sqlite3, and they need to be encrypted. And when i want to retrieve values they need to be decrypted. Now I'm getting this error `TypeError: token must be bytes`. Here is the full list of errors: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\d\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Assignment8\CDMS.py", line 75, in <module> get_clients() File "C:\Users\d\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Assignment8\CDMS.py", line 68, in get_clients new += fernet.decrypt(i).decode() + " " File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token) File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 100, in _get_unverified_token_data utils._check_bytes("token", token) File "C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\cryptography\utils.py", line 29, in _check_bytes raise TypeError("{} must be bytes".format(name)) TypeError: token must be bytes`

Here is my code:

```
from Classes import Client
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import sqlite3


key = Fernet.generate_key()

fernet = Fernet(key)
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def insert_client(client):
    fullname = fernet.encrypt(client.fullname.encode())
    fullname1 = fullname.decode()
    adress = fernet.encrypt(client.adress.encode())
    adress1 = adress.decode()
    zipcode = fernet.encrypt(client.zipcode.encode())
    zipcode1 = zipcode.decode()
    city = fernet.encrypt(client.city.encode())
    city1 = city.decode()
    email = fernet.encrypt(client.email.encode())
    email1 = email.decode()
    mphone = fernet.encrypt(client.mphone.encode())
    mphone1 = mphone.decode()
    
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO client VALUES (:fullname, :adress, :zipcode, :city, :email, :mphone)",
          {'fullname': fullname1, 'adress': adress1, 'zipcode': zipcode1,
           'city': city1, 'email': email1, 'mphone': mphone1})

client1 = Client('Name1', 'Street1', 'Zipcode', 'NewYork', '123@gmail.com', '12345678')

def get_clients():
    arr = []
    new = ""
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM client")
    arr = c.fetchall()
    for i in arr:
        new += fernet.decrypt(i).decode() + " "
    return new
        


insert_client(client1)
get_clients()


conn.close()
```

The first function is for adding clients, by a class object named Client. And the second function is for retrieving all values decrypted.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314081/python-fernet-typeerror-token-must-be-bytes) out

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall` returns an iterable of *rows* (most commonly tuples). If you want to only process one record, you should instead use `fetchone`:

```
...
arr = c.fetchone()
for i in arr:
    new += fernet.decrypt(i).decode() + " "
...
```

Alternatively you could iterate the cursor and return a list:

```
def get_clients():
    arr = []
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM client")
    for row in c:
        new = ""
        for i in row:
            new += fernet.decrypt(i).decode() + " "
        arr.append(new)
    return arr
```

But the *Pythonic* way would be to use comprehensions:

```
def get_clients():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM client")
    return [' '.join(fernet.decrypt(i).decode() for i in row)
            for row in c]
```

Slightly shorter, isn't it?